# Magento: jQuery in custom file does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, magento

So I am trying to add some simple jQuery to a magento-theme.
I have put my jQuery in an external file, which lies in the "js" (skin/frontend/default/myTheme/js) folder of the theme.
Here is the link to my site: `http://shop.veivecouture.com/`
I am including it in the page.xml file with the following method:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/functions.js</name></action>
```

I have also tried:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>../skin/frontend/default/trego/js/functions.js</script></action>
```

I put them both in the "Head" block like this:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
   <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>  
   <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

   <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/functions.js</name></action> <!-- my line -->

    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
</block>
```

I can get to both files via "view source", so the linking seems to be right, however no jQuery takes effect.
What am I doing wrong?

This is the javascript in the functions.js file:

```
$('.block-content').hide(); //edit by Carl Papworth
$('.block-title').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.block-content').show();
    $('.close-block').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.block-content').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the file into magento js folder and try

```
    <action method="addJs"><script>js/your_custom_folder/functions.js</script></action>
```

Comment: Where do I find that file? right now it lies in (skin/frontend/default/myTheme/js)

Comment: In magento's main directory, with skin,app,lib,var and other folders

Comment: Tried it, and file is found no problem, but no jQuery takes effect.

Comment: write `$.noConflict();` in start of the your functions.js or `$j = $.noConflict();` and use $j instead of $

Comment: Try looking with firebug, its prototype and jquery conflict, change the sequence of calling the files it maybe solve the problem or add noConflict() to your file

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `jQuery.noConflict();` at the very bottom of your js file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your head part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/specification.js');?>" media="screen"></script>
```